# Is there a better way to say "fast-moving rollercoaster car"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am not sure why, but it sounds awfully unidiomatic, but I can't think of a better way to say it. I am not sure if I should even use the word car, and if I should even use rollercoaster as a noun adjective.

For example:

> He was listening to music inside the fast-moving rollercoaster car
>   before the car jumped out of the track and led him to his death.

Comment: For one thing, roller coasters use cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, "He was listening to music inside the careening rollercoaster car before the car jumped the rails and plunged, taking him to his death.

See "careen" as a verb here:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/careen#English,

especially meaning number six.